# Does the item after the last item in a linked list have the value of 0?

Tags: c++, linked-list, quicksort

I am writing a quick sort algorithm for homework but I was wondering if my loop will stop too early. Will the while loop go past the last element and stop or will it keep reading random numbers that were left over in the memory? Does that make sense?

```
void ListP::partition(ListNode * &Larger, ListNode * &Smaller, ListNode * &pivot ){
    ListNode *curr, *temps, *templ; *temps= *templ = NULL;
    curr=pivot->next;
    pivot->next=NUll;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        if (curr->item<=pivot->item){
            if(Smaller==NULL){
                Smaller=curr;
                curr=curr->next;
                Smaller->next=NULL;
                temps=Smaller;
            }
            else{
                temps->next=curr;
                curr=curr->next;
                temps=temps->next;
                temps->next=NUll;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(Larger==NULL){
                Larger=curr;
                curr=curr->next;
                Larger->next=NULL;
                templ=Larger;
            }
            else{
                templ->next=curr;
                curr=curr->next;
                templ=templ->next;
                templ->next=NUll;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `*temps= *templ = NULL;`  --> I'm confused.  What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: What is `ListP`? Also I don't see a way that `templ` will ever be anything other than `NULL`. It starts as `NULL` and the only time you assign to it is when you give it the value of `Larger`, but that only happens if `Larger` is `NULL`!

Comment: *"the item after the last item"* there can be, by definition, no such item. Otherwise what you considered to be the last item would not have been the last item.

Comment: @scohe001 -- `*templ` is assigned to `NULL` which is likely already a bug. `templ` is uninitialized (until later).  We don't know the value of `Larger` as passed by the caller.

Comment: This isn't a standard C++ `list` class, so your best bet would to be ask the author, although I suspect that any sensible linked list would set `last->next` as `nullptr`.

Comment: Why do you need 8 pointers to do this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the item after the last item in a linked list have the value of 0?

By definition, there is no item after the last item. If there was an item after the last item, then the one before would not be the last.

> I was wondering if my loop will stop too early.
>    Will the while loop go past the last element

At a quick glance, all branches of the loop do `curr=curr->next`, and the loop end condition is `curr!=NULL`, so the loop will end after a node whose `next` is null. If `next` of the last node of your list points to null, then the loop shouln't go past it. `next` of a node before the last item cannot point to null, so the loop shouldn't end too early either.

However, if `next` of the last item of the list doesn't point to null, then the loop won't end on that node.

You should verify that the program behaves the way you expect it to behave by using a debugger.